# How to get these two Python scripty to work together?

Tags: python, text, full-text-search, phrase

- (1) Below is a code I have written to look into a file, find my search
  phrase and copy that line.

```html
with open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Output.txt") as infile:
        with open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Input.txt", "w") as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                if "This Phrase:" in line:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

- (2) Below is a second section of code I have written to search a file for a "Start phrase" and "End Phrase", and copy out all the lines in-between into a new file. This also works.

But I don't seem to be able to combine them to work together! Keep getting errors when I try, every way I try. Python beginner.

In the files I am trying to search the above code (1) needs to carry out its action, then code (2) needs to carry out its action after, in that order.

```
with open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Output.txt") as infile, open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Input.txt", "w") as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start-Prase":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "End-Phrase":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following:

```
with open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Output.txt") as infile, open("C:\Python34\Python Code\Input.txt", "w") as outfile:
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Start-Phrase":
        copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "End-Phrase":
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        if "This Phrase:" in line:
                outfile.write(line)
```

I wasn't certain if you are trying to write out every line or just some lines. You also may need to split your lines (text) apart, depending on how they are formatted.

Comment: I need - if "This Phrase:" in line: outfile.write(line) - this section of code to search the start of the file then the second code to work after that. I tried your suggestion before posting. Thanks, but it doesn't work.  - if "This Phrase:" in line: outfile.write(line)  - only needs to write one line once phrase is found, then for the second code to do it's work after that.

Comment: Also you way throws up an error - #"expected an indented block" for the word copy on the second line.

Comment: Hey @JoeF, I will take another look at this - I think there is a spacing error in the code as-is. Can you give an example of what the text file looks like, and what the expected output would be? Thanks!

Comment: bla bla bla_This Phrase-(Email address-copy this line)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
bla bla bla_Start-Prase
copy this and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
bla bla bla_End-Phrase (end copy here, then repeat both steps again in the rest of file)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
bla bla bla_This Phrase-(Email address-copy this line)and so on........

Comment: Copy these two comments into note pad and the make more sence. This is what the end result document should look like.

bla bla bla_This Phrase-(Email address-copy this line)

bla bla bla_Start-Prase
copy this and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
and this
bla bla bla_End-Phrase (end copy here, then repeat both steps again in the rest of file)

Comment: I couldnt seem to attached the above two comment as txt files so had to put them in as comments. Please let me know if the comments above dont make sense to you.